# Deleting a specific node in a singly linked list(java)

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

So my problem is that I wanna delete a node based on a value inputted by the user, in my program I can already, add, search, and delete the node in the last position, but so far I haven't been able to delete a specific value inputted by the user, if for example I have 1,2,3,4 elements in my list I wanna be able to point at, say 2, and delete it. here are my functions, the last one is the uncompleted one:

```
//searches node
public void searchNode(int input){
    Node temp = first;
    boolean found = false;

    if(!isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0 ; i<size ; i ++){
          if(temp.value == input){
             System.out.println(input + " found in the position: " + (i+1));
             found = true;
             break;
            }
            temp = temp.rightNode;
        }
    if(!found)
        System.out.println("value not found.");
        }
    }

//deletes last node
public void deleteLastNode(){
    if(isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("There are no nodes to delete.");
    }

    if(last == first){
       first = null;
       last = null;
    } else {
       Node current = first;
       while(current.rightNode != last){
       current = current.rightNode;
    }
       current.rightNode = null;
       last = current;
    }
 size --;
}


//delete element, input by user.
public void deleteInputByUser(int input) {
   Node temp = first;
   boolean found = false;

   if(isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("There are no nodes to delete.");
   } else {

      }
   size--;  
}


//Node class
public class Node{
int value;
Node rigthNode;

public Node(int value){
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Which data structure have you used? e.g. ``ArrayList`` , ``Array``, ``Map``

Comment: What data is in your `Node`, and you want to delete a `Node` which `data` is equal to `input` or index equal to `input`?

Comment: Can you add your Node class to your question?

Comment: I'm not using a data structure, i'll edit my post to add the Node class.

Comment: @GermanG. did you see my answer? it should help you

Comment: yes thank you, your answer along with Brian Vanover's both worked. I wish I could check both answers as the right answer tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deletion of a node in a `Linked List` by value is not so bad. This pseudocode should help you get started:

```
deleteNodeByValue(int val) {
  if (head.val = val) {
    head = head.next
    return
  }
  current = head
  while (current.next != null) {
    if (current.next.val = val) {
      current.next = current.next.next
      return
    }
    current = current.next
  } 
}
```

Comment: Great answer, better explained than in the book "Introduction to algorithms". thank you, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that.

```
public void deleteNodeByValue(int input) {
    Node currNode = first;
    boolean found = false;
    Node prevNode = first;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (currNode.value == input) {
                ///////DELETE START
                if (currNode == first) {
                    first = currNode.rightNode;
                } else {
                    prevNode.rightNode = currNode.rightNode;
                    if (currNode == last) 
                        last = prevNode;
                }
                ////DELETE END
                found = true;
                size--;
                break;
            }
            prevNode = currNode;
            currNode = currNode.rightNode;
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println("value not found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `nodeToDelete` and his `previousNode`, then

```
previousNode.rightNode = nodeToDelete.rightNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way. The following code will remove the element once the index is given.

```
public boolean deleteAt(int index){
    Node current=first;
    if(index==0){
        first=current.rightNode;
        return true;
    }
    currentIndex=0;
    previousNode=first;
    current=first.rightNode;
    while(current!=null){
        if(currentIndex==index){
            previousNode.rightNode=current.rightNode;
            return true;
        }
        currentIndex++;
        previousNode=current;
        current=current.rightNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```